# How to separate columns with a $ in C

Tags: c

I want to read values in columns separated with a `$`.

It should read the student ID, name, Assignments grade, quizzes grade,
Midterm grade, Practical exam grade, and final exam grade.

Each column should be separated by a `$`

How can I do all of this in the C language?

```
1172121$Imad Qahtani$85$88$77.8$66.67$90.5
1202145$Saja Qanatra$75$78$87.8$65.67$83.5
1187458$Salem Abdalhafeez$85$88$77.8$66.67$77.5
1197845$Tarek Masoud$85$88$77.8$66.67$67.5
1204587$Tala Hamdan$85$88$77.8$66.67$95.5
```

Comment: The [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function comes to mind.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `strtok` is not you friend: empty columns will be mishandled.

Answer (score 1):

You can read input lines with `fgets()` and parse them with `sscanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char line[100];
    int student_ID;
    char name[32];
    float assignments_grade, quizzes_grade, midterm_grade, practical_exam_grade, final_exam_grade;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        if (sscanf(line, "%d$%31[^$]$%f$%f$%f$%f$%f",
                   &student_ID, name,
                   &assignments_grade, &quizzes_grade, &midterm_grade,
                   &practical_exam_grade, &final_exam_grade) != 7) {
            printf("invalid format: %s\n", line);
        } else {
            printf("                  ID: %d\n", student_ID);
            printf("                name: %s\n", name);
            printf("   assignments_grade: %.2f\n", assignments_grade);
            printf("       quizzes_grade: %.2f\n", quizzes_grade);
            printf("       midterm_grade: %.2f\n", midterm_grade);
            printf("practical_exam_grade: %.2f\n", practical_exam_grade);
            printf("    final_exam_grade: %.2f\n", final_exam_grade);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @FajoolStore: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.